# How to initialize a structure on definition?

Tags: c, struct, initialization-list

Is there a way to declare a structure with default initalisation values?

I have a header file which defines a structur like this:

```
typedef struct struc_s
{
    size_t cost const = 2000;
    size_t dmg const = 100;
    size_t def const = 100;
    size_t hull const = 1500;
    size_t shield const = 300;
    size_t capacity const = 2;
    size_t destruc const = 10;
} struc_t;
```

But this ofcourse doesn't work.

I would also be fine with a way of declaring a var of type `struc_t` in this header file. But as I remember right. I would have to decalre it in the c file as `extern`

What I want to do is every where where this header is included i want to be able to do `var = struc_s.dmg` and and the result should be that var holds the value `100`.
But I dont want to declare struc_s anywhere else then in the header. Is there a way to archive this behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not in the way you want.

When you do a typedef, you're defining the *shape* of a memory region, a process distinct from allocating and filling it.

A possible alternative:

```
typedef struct 
{
    size_t cost;
    size_t dmg;
    size_t def;
    size_t hull;
    size_t shield;
    size_t capacity;
    size_t destruc;
} struc_t;


#ifndef DEFAULT_STRUC_VALUES_DEFINED
#define DEFAULT_STRUC_VALUES_DEFINED 

const struc_t DEFAULT_STRUC = {
    .cost = 2000,
    .dmg = 100,
    .def = 100,
    .hull = 1500,
    .shield = 300,
    .capacity = 2,
    .destruc = 10
};
#endif
```

and then when you want to create a new one:

```
struc_t *new_struc = malloc(sizeof(struc_t));
memcpy(new_struc, DEFAULT_STRUC, sizeof(struc_t));
```

As a sidenote, is there a reason you're using `size_t` for your structure members? There's nothing inherently wrong with it, but it may change from platform to platform.

Comment: would be default struct be accesable forom evrywhere, where it is included without doint something like `extern const struc_t DEFAULT_STRUC`? than that would be fine for me, i just want a struct that contains thoose values without to declare + initialize it explicit.

Comment: And I like to use size_t just because it is as far as I know the size of cpu orating width. So... I jsut like size_t I don't have a realy good reason for.

Comment: Updated answer with an `#ifndef` that'll make sure this does what you want. 
That said, there's nothing wrong with putting the `DEFAULT_STRUC` in a .c file and doing `extern const struc_t DEFAULT_STRUC` in the header.

Comment: ah i guess you missunderstood me, but anyway, your answer does exactly what I'm looking for, thanks.

Comment: Glad to be of service, then :)

Comment: It can also be done with a define: `#define DEFAULT_STRUC ((const struc_t) {.cost = 2000, .dmg = 100})`

Answer (score 1):

```
typedef struct struc_s
{
int a;
int b;    
}s;
```

This is type definition and Not a declaration of object.You can initialize at the time of declaring object.

C89-style initializers are used when contiguous members may be given.

```
s obj={1,2};
```

For non contiguous or out of order members list, designated initializer style may be used

```
s obj={.a=1,.b=2};  

     or

s obj={.b=2,.a=1};
```

A third way is copy the value of an existing object of the same type

```
s obj1=obj;
```